# Curses app throws _curses.error: init_pair() returned ERR

Tags: python, linux

I have a problem whenever i run my curses application,it always runs fine on windows(thanks to windows-curses module) and other Linux Distros,but since i have Garuda Linux installed i want to run the app on it.but the problem is,whenever i run the app it yields the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/justaus3r/Desktop/Programming/Python/Projects/ANFU/Anfu.py", line 564, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(Main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "/home/justaus3r/Desktop/Programming/Python/Projects/ANFU/Anfu.py", line 330, in Main
    curses.init_pair(69, curses.COLOR_MAGENTA, -1)
_curses.error: init_pair() returned ERR
```

i have tried it with different terminals like xterm and Alacritty.it throws the same error,does my code has some problems or the module isn't compatible with Garuda Linux.any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was gettiing same issue in redhat - maipo

this worked for me

export TERM=xterm-256color